# How to probe UART pins of a phone?

Tags: uart, multimeter, probe, logic-analyzer

I'm gonna try to probe this phone for UART pins: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scsAlvMie1M

I have a cheap logic analyzer and just bought really pointy probing pins (waiting to arrive), I also have an FTDI cable/breakout board, with 5v and 3.3v

On the right, on top of the battery, there are 4 pins that look like could be UART ones. How do I probe them?

First of all, do I have to share the ground of my logic analyzer or UART cable, with the ground of the phone?

Are there things that I should do for greater chances of success?

Comment: `do I have to share the ground?` ... can you measure voltage with only one probe on the voltmeter? ... can you light a bulb by connecting only one wire?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Yes, connect phone GND (e.g. RF shields) to FTDI and analyser GND. Make some measurements and edit this question.

Comment: @jsotola should I put my FTDI in 3.3v or 5v?

Comment: I would not assume that the phone uses those voltages

Comment: @jsotola is there something I can do to expect the case where the phone has lower voltages?

Comment: 1.8V would be my guess for the UART, but this is something you probably have to measure.

Comment: @user1850479 so I should put a resistor between the TX and RX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an FTDI to 'probe' would not be recommended, as the inputs are not high impedance and it's possible that you could damage either port especially if you probed something the was logic level high and the other was low and they were both outputs. It would be better to use a logic analyzer, that has a high impedance which means not much current can flow into the analyzer.

> First of all, do I have to share the ground of my logic analyzer or
> UART cable, with the ground of the phone?

Yes, you need a ground reference to determine a voltage with most logic analyzers, especially the cheap ones which usually have one ground pin. The ground pin needs to be connected to the device you are measuring. Usually the ground is tied together (and not isolated) on most devices. If you have a multimeter you can start probing capacitors (usually power bypass capacitors have one side connected to ground), looking for pins that are tied together by a single net. USB ground may also be tied to everything. Once you find a ground, you can connect the logic analyzer probe to ground to that and start using the probes of the logic analyzer.

Many of the cheap logic analyzers also have an oscilloscope function, use one of those to probe around because then the voltage levels can be seen. If you don't, set the logic analyzer's voltage trigger level to a low value, like 1V and probe until you see the values changing.

Comment: I'll use the saleae one I have here, I believe it has a UART function

Comment: You can decode serial (you'll need to know the protocol), use just the logic analyzer to find the signals, then you can try and decode them.